# Does the bash shell consider an assignment like "fact=2" as integer or long?

Tags: bash, types, scripting, integer

Does the bash shell consider variable `fact` as integer or long by default if you are making an assignment like below?

```
fact=2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither. It's treated as a string. All shell variable values are strings unless declared otherwise (e.g. with `declare -i fact`, a non-standard shell extension). The question of "how many bits are there and is there a sign" only becomes meaningful when you do arithmetic expansion with `$(())` or pass variable values as arguments to other tools like `expr` or `bc`.

The [POSIX Shell Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) for Arithmetic Expansion says

> Only signed long integer arithmetic is required.

The bash manual only guarantees

> Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with  no  check
>   for  overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error.

Since C guarantees `signed long` to be >= 32 bits, you can safely assume at least 32 bit signed arithemetic. I'd expect 64 bits on 64bit systems.

Comment: On 64 bit systems does the size of integer is 64 bits in C? I think it should be 32 bits. Correct me if I'm wrong here?

Comment: It depends. I've programmed systems where all types except `char` where 64 bit, even `short`. Those were Cray Unicos number crunchers. The C language only defines minimum widths, so there is no requirement that `int` be 32bit. For `int` it may be anything >= 16bit.

Comment: Is Cray Unicos a 64 bit OS? So what decides the size of int or long in C? Could a 32 bit OS have 64 bit as the size of int

Comment: Yes, Unicos is a 64bit OS. The size of `int` or `long` is set by the C compiler implementation/vendor. Some implementations may allow to select a size with an option (similar to the old DOS days with small, medium, large memory models). Yes, in theory, a 32bit OS may support 64bit `int`. This would not violate the C Language spec.

Comment: So it is possible to have int size of 64 bit in a 32 bit OS. But it should be costly for the application to address the int data in this case?

Comment: Right. It may be a performance hit, but that may be offset by not having to write your own 32bit*32bit = 64bit multiplication. Everything is an engineering tradeoff.

Comment: Its a performance hit because you can't generate the 64 bit address in one instruction (you will need 2 instructions) if you are using a 32 bit OS right?

Comment: No (32 bit OSs don't have 64 bit addresses). It's a performance hit because you may need two 32bit loads/stores if you do not have 64bit *registers* and if the ALU doesn't support 64bit operands, in which case you need several instructions for all arithmetic.

Comment: Yeah that's right. Thanks for helping me understand it. I was just wondering why doesn't a binary built on 32-bit OS run on 64 bit OS?

Comment: You're welcome. The next step would be to accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of this answer.

Comment: I was just wondering why doesn't a binary built on 32-bit OS run on 64 bit OS? I feel it should be able to run because 64 bit OS can generate 32 bit addresses. Vice versa may not be possible i.e. running binary which is built on 64-bit OS on 32-bit OS.

Comment: With proper OS support this *does* work for selectes CPU architectures (i386 on i86_64, or sparc32 on sparc64). But we're straying from the question's title. Feel free to ask a new question, but note it should be about programming to be on-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks Jens. I have posted a new question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882660/running-binary-built-on-32-bit-os-to-run-on-64-bit-os

Comment: @bourne If you're able to use C99 don't forget about `stdint.h` (and cstdint). I use those types wherever possible.