# Running binary built on 32-bit OS to run on 64-bit OS

Tags: operating-system

Is it always possible to build a binary built on 32-bit OS to run on 64-bit OS? If not what cases it is possible and when it is not possible. 
If it is not possible why is it not possible in some cases?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your OS. On Windows all 32 Bit binarys should also run on 64 Bit. On Linux it also works if you install the 32 Bit librarys. On BSD it's the same as on Linux AFAIK.

Comment: Why is it not possible to run the binary built on 32 bit linux OS on 64 bit linux?

Comment: I think that's because usually the 32-bit Binarys are linked against 32-bit librarys. However, as I said, you can just install the 32-bit libs on your 64-bit OS.

Comment: How do I install 32 bit libs on 64 bit OS?

Comment: @bourne Which Linux distro? Usually it's a matter of selecting the right package with the distro's package manager.

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu: "apt-get install ia32-libs" gives a basic set of 32 bit libs. On Redhat and derivates you can usually just "yum install YOUR_LIBRARY.i386"